# How to scroll to top of the page with Javascript, after printing the final results with the function document.write()

Tags: javascript, scroll, reload

Sorry my inexperience

Basically my JS code is composed of one form with inputs, a press buton and the final results which are printed using the function document.write()

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="lavagens" size="3" MAXLENGTH="3" value="30"> INPUT<br>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Calc" onClick="calcula_custos_auto()"><br> 
</form>

function calcula_custos_auto(){    
a+b+c*d; //some calculations with inputs
document.write("a lot of results"); //print results on screen
window.scrollTo(0,0); //doesn't work
}
```

The problem is after it prints all these results, which occupy a lot of lines, the screen does not go to top. The scrollTo(0,0) method does't seem to work. How can I solve this issue?

By the way, how can I also create a button, to reload the page again so the user can input values again?

Thank you so very much

Comment: You should not use document.write after the page load. Learn DOM methods like createElement, appendChild, and innerHTML

Comment: hi, thank you, and on this particular case, which DOM moethods shall I use? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

a+b+c*d throws an exception:

```
ReferenceError: a is not define
```

So it will never reach the rest of the code in that function, hence it will not scroll.

Comment: It's not a jQuery extension.. jQuery doesn't create random global methods. This is effectively the same as `.scrollTo`.

Comment: Adjusted answer after investigation.

Comment: How could the `document.write` print the results if it was causing error the line above? The code is obviously just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="lavagens" size="3" MAXLENGTH="3" value="30"> INPUT<br>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Calc" onClick="calcula_custos_auto()"><br> 
<div id'resultDiv'></div>
</form>

function calcula_custos_auto(){    
a+b+c*d; //some calculations with inputs
var div = document.getElementById('resultDiv');
div.innerHTML= 'Put Your Result here';
window.scroll(0,1);
}
```

We that your result shows on current form without reloading and you need not to add input box and button again.

Comment: sorry, Now finally I've finisehd my code!!!
How do you do that? What var is resultDiv ?
thank you

Comment: do you mean this???
http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/tryit.asp?filename=try_getelementbyid